# Delegate does not implement session:didReceiveApplicationContext:

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to send data from my iOS app to my Watch App.
The sending of the data seems to work but the reception don't.

When the Watch app receipts a data, it gives me this exception:

> [WC] -[WCSession handleApplicationContextWithPairingID:]_block_invoke_2 delegate RSense_Watch_App_Extension.WatchSessionManager does not implement session:didReceiveApplicationContext:

The problem is that I do have the above mentioned function implemented.

This is from my Watch App:

```
extension WatchSessionManager {

// Receiver
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {
        print("Data Received")
    })

}
```

The iOS and Watch App are correctly paired, and the session is okay too.

Can you find what is strugling?

Comment: Note that in current Swift, you should use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`, and the current declaration of the method use ` [String : Any]`.

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2016/12/passing-data-to-apple-watch-app-from.html) does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Larme and @pkc456 I found the issue.

I just added public to my function and changer the parameter "AnyObject" to "Any".

Here is the function updated:

```
public func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {
        print("Data Received")
    })

}
```

It works now.